# how we can Save into table relation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

what i usually does for saving to 2 tables that has a relationship is save using their repository, which is for me is like a double task, like this

```
tableARepository.save(tableA);

tableBRepository.save(tableB);
```

so does spring provide a solution for this kind of case ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use SpringJPA (with a suitable backend such as hibernate), then you will be able to define the relationships in the entities, and JPA will look after it or you. (With proper coding)

Comment: yeah i use SpringJPA , but i cant seem find and example code for the issue i had @jr593

Answer (score 0):

Please see link: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-cascade-persist-operation-child-entities/ and instead of `entityManager.persist(entity);` you can call `parentRepository.save(entity);`, but all the definitions of child relations mentioned in the article will be the same.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a relationship between your tables, i suggest you to use annotations like @OneToOne, @OneToMany... in order to create a relation between your tables and consequently to save in one action instead